# Guardar la salida de un find en un array desde el exec

Tags: bash, find, exec

Parto de un array con los archivos que quiero buscar dentro de un directorio (imagenes).
Hago un búsqueda y según las coincidencias quiero dos respuestas diferentes.
La primera no tiene importancia y de momento la muestro en pantalla con '-printf'.
La segunda quiero que se guarde en un array que ya he declarado antes.

```
  declare -a imagenes=( movie poster fanart cover folder )
  declare -a imagen
  declare actual=$1

        for img in "${imagenes[@]}"; do find "${actual}" -type f \
                      \( -iname *-${img}.??? -printf '\nno -> %s\t%p' \) , \
                      \( -iname *${img}.??? -exec imagen+=( '{}' ) \; \)
                      done
```

Al ejecutar el programa recibo los siguientes errores:

```
 error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('
línea 296: `                      \( -iname *${img}.??? -exec imagen+=( '{}' ) \; \)'
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Me parece que olvidaste escapar los paréntesis de `imagen+=( '{}' )`, es decir, `imagen+=\( '{}' \)`

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero sigo sin poder hacerlo. Me parece que dentro del '-exec' simplemente no se puede asignar valores a un array...

Comment: Intenta usar https://www.shellcheck.net para mejorar el formato de tu código y vuélvelo a poner en tu post para que te podamos ayudar con más facilidad